# Power BI RankX function

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a simple table ,Sales with just product,Quantity , and totalsales.

I am trying to rank product based on total sales.

m1=rankx('sales','sales'[totalsales])

It is giving me all sort of errors.

Answer (score 0):

To get the products based on order of total sales use the following steps:

1. Create a Total Sales measure :

   TotalSalesMeasure = Sum('Product'[TotalSales])
2. Use the above measure in your DAX to calculate RANK
     RankProduct = RANKX(ALLSELECTED('Product'[Product]),[TotalSalesMeasure],,DESC,Skip)

Hope this solves your issue.

Best Regards,

Shani Noorudeen

Comment: Yes, that works..but I do not understand why we sum it? Can we not rank the totalsales column directly?Sum will be a total of all totalsales,right?

Comment: The expression should return a single scalar value, thats why we use aggregation there. Either as a measure or use functions like sum,count etc.Please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax.